# What port(s) does sharepoint designer need to have opened?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We'd like to communicate with sharepoint 2010 from sharepoint designer from a desktop inside the dmz. What ports need to be opened to allow sharepoint designer to do its thing?

Do the ports of Sharepoint Web Services have to be opened?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only need the 80 TCP port, because it is only using the FrontPage Server Extensions.  You do access the server like if you were on the web version.

See [here](http://www.sharepoint2007security.com/guidance/firewall_rules)

Answer (score 2):

it depedns on what port(s) is your sharepoint running. Usualy it should be TCP 80 or/and 443.

Comment: well by default its 80 but upon installation the admin couls have used another port apart from 80.Look at your documentations

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very nice listing of the ports needed. 
http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/02/21/tcpip-ports-of-sharepoint-2013/